# An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: ArgumentCountError Message: Too few arguments to function Active::payments_status(), 0 passed in

Tags: codeigniter

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function Active::payments_status(), 0 passed in /pluxinfosystems/richard/public_html/pscs/admin/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected

Filename: /pluxinfosystems/richard/public_html/pscs/admin/application/controllers/Active.php

Line Number: 451

Backtrace:

File: /pluxinfosystems/richard/public_html/pscs/admin/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function Active::payments_status(), 0 passed in /pluxinfosystems/richard/public_html/pscs/admin/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and its linked resources.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.